# Visual Studio 2012 won't run .JS files that work fine outside VS?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a couple of .JS files that I need to use in my project.  The files work fine when I build a regular html page outside VS, but when I run my project with the files in use they just don't work.  I can't figure out why.  I am implementing a fallback for CSS3 column split in IE.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_script/css3-multi-column.js"></script>
```

I am including the file above, in a CSS file i set the column-count:5; This is working perfect when i build a simple html page with notepad but when i just implement it in my project it doesent do anything?!

Comment: Can you define "don't work"?

Comment: Show us the markup where you are referencing the JS files?

Comment: Updated my question =) I realy need help with this, spent way to many hours figuring this out..

Comment: View the source of the page when you think it "should" be working.  Is your javascript code included / referenced / accessible?

Comment: Show us your directory structure?

Comment: did you try something like `src="../../script/css3-multi-column.js`?

Comment: Sorry for a late response.. Thank you IrishChieftain, your question of the directory structure gave me the answer, i was simply pointing it to the wrong path.. I solved it by putting ../ in front of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when you have a problem like this, there are a couple steps to debugging:

First go into your browser's developer tools (once the site is running) and look to see what errors occur. If the JS file is not loading, then you can deduce that you are not pointing to the correct path in your file structure. If this is the case, then you need to figure out how to properly reference the script. If you are using ASP.NET MVC, you can reference your scripts like:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myscript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This references the script from the root (~) of the project. Otherwise, you may have to do something like, `../../Scripts/myscript.js` as your script path where the ../ is based on the position of the view that is accessing the script relative to the Scripts directory.

Another possible error is that there is something wrong with your script. Since you said the site worked already (outside of VS2012), then I will assume that the script itself is okay.

As others have said, if you can provide an error in your question that gives more detail, we can provide better support.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably in this directory, check and correct a reference in its attempts to use,    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"